# Nginx routes and refresh cause 404

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've set up an Express and React website using nginx and Elastic Beanstalk. It works fine when navigating the website, but if I refresh on a route other than the home route, or try type in a specific route other than the home route it causes a 404.

I've found a lot of different solutions to do with changing the `nginx.config`, and think I'm one step away. This is my current `nginx.config`:

```
server {

      listen 80;
      server_name leaftherapyeb-env.eba-xyc63u32.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com www.leaftherapyeb-env.eba-xyc63u32.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com;
 
      root /var/www/leaftherapyeb-env.eba-xyc63u32.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com;
      index index.html;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
    }
```

I've seen a lot of solutions suggesting to use `root /usr/share/nginx/html;`, however when I use this instead of the root above every page links to the nginx index.html. So I changed to try the root as the path to the domain, which I think I have wrong, but don't know how to work out the path, and currently causes 500 internal error on every route including the home route.

Any help would be massively appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is your react source code located?

Comment: https://github.com/dbacall/leaf

Comment: Hi, I mean, how do you build your react application, i.e. yarn build, and where do you put the resulting dist folder? You should point your nginx root to the dist folder

Comment: I think you should keep the root `root /var/www/html;` and not use the server name as the root folder

Comment: So I do `npm run build` which creates a build folder in the client folder. I tried to link to it earlier but I don't think I was getting the path right. Would it just be `/var/client/build`?

Comment: btw, `root` can only be inside a `location` directive, thats why you getting a 500 internal server error.

Comment: so with `root /var/www/html;` in the location directive I'm getting a 403 forbidden when I try load the website...

Comment: and have this error in the eb logs, `directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.31.30.241, server: leaftherapyeb-env.eba-xyc63u32.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "leaftherapyeb-env.eba-xyc63u32.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"`

Comment: maybe my answer will help you?

Answer (score 1):

I think your nginx config has the wrong syntax. In the below nginx.conf, the / location points to your index.html in the folder /var/www/html

```
server {

      listen 80;
      server_name leaftherapyeb-env.eba-xyc63u32.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com www.leaftherapyeb-env.eba-xyc63u32.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com;
 
      location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
    }
```

You need to manually copy all the content of the client/build folder to /var/www/html - or you can just create a symlink (which is IMO not the very best solution, but it should work)

```
ln -s client/build /var/www/html
```

If you want to work with a symlink, make sure to remove the folder before creating the symlink otherwise you get an error

Comment: I have found a build folder inside client: https://github.com/dbacall/leaf/tree/main/client/build - if you want nginx to serve this folder, then just make sure all the build folders content is inside the /var/www/html folder, so nginx can find the index.html

Comment: So I'm a bit confused where `/var/www/html` actually is located? Where would I run `ln -s client/build /var/www/html`? Sorry for my ignorance, this is my first day with nginx and elastic beanstalk.

Comment: yeah so I don't understand how I'd get the build folder inside the `/var/www/html` folder or where that folder is

Comment: Ok so `/var` is on my local system? But there's no `/www` inside it...

Comment: then create it! mkdir /var/www and then use the ln command to softlink the build folder

Comment: ok, so I made changed permission, made /www, ran the ln command, but when I try cd into /var/www/html there's nothing there and the website still gives 403 forbidden

Comment: Something I'm wondering is nginx seems to be able to find `/usr/share/nginx/html`, but when I cd into `/usr/share/nginx` nginx doesn't exist, so maybe it shouldn't be `/var/www/html`

Comment: yeah so I've had a research and don't think the `/var/www/html` nginx looks for is my own directory, so symlinking on my own directory does nothing